# Emacs + ipython tab completion not working ("no match")

Tags: emacs, ipython

I am using emacs with elpy, and ipython as interpreter. After a general upgrade of the python packages today, tab completion stopped working in ipython, always gives "no match" message. Does anybody know why might this be?

Tab completion does work though in Ipython when run directly in the terminal, only fails when inside an emacs buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems this was an issue in IPython 7.2.0, it has been fixed in 7.3 so you can just upgrade and it should work.

See https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/11541